# setTimeout/setInmmediate/nextTick makes a function asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, settimeout

Days ago, i was thinking (totally noob in node) that, for a magical reason, if i create a function that receives a callback, it will be asynchronous:

```
function fakeAsync(someArgument, callback) {
     //Do some work
     callback()
}
```

It appears to my poor logic and little tests i made that things doesn't work like that :P So i went to Node's fs.readFile source and try to figure out what makes that function asynchronous. The truth is i didn't understand so much, but i see a call to process.nextTick (if my memory is not failing). I ended reading about async patterns and so on, but i just feel i don't understand the basic aspects.

**Question:** The use of process.nextTick/setImmediate (node) and setTimeout (js in browser) makes a function async? For example:

```
var array_to_fill = []

function async_fill(elements, array, callback) {
    process.nextTick(()=>{
       elements.forEach((e)=>{array.push(e)})
       callback(array) 
    });
}


async_fill([1,2,3], array_to_fill, (array)=>{
    console.log(array)
})
console.log('This is displayed first!')
```

Is this really asynchronous? Is this what makes the Promise's "then" async too (i read somewhere that A+ requires 'then' in async fhasion)? Also, is the array's forEach method interfering with the "possible" asynchrony of the function due it's blocking nature?

I'm really lost about it. Any help will be appreciated. Oh, and sorry my bad english :)

Advanced thanks!

Comment: well... forEach is always synchronous, but it's called asynchronously by not executing it until the next tick, which allows the rest of the code to run and the callstack to clear before the forEach starts.

Comment: `setTimeout` , `setInterval` and `Web Workers` can be used to build async codes

Comment: @Saba But in server-side process.nextTick can be used too?